# Builder's XmlMarkup object loses constants?

Tags: ruby, namespaces, constants, metaprogramming, eigenclass

I try to upgrade a legacy application from Ruby 1.8.7 to 2.2.3. Afterwards the rendering of [builder](http://builder.rubyforge.org/) templates raises errors about unknown classes.

> uninitialized constant Builder::XmlMarkup::BigDecimal (NameError)

It seem that within the Builder::XmlMarkup constants like classes disappear.

```
### example.xml.builder (template) ###
BigDecimal.new('23') # no error

class << xml
  def some
    data(BigDecimal.new('23')) # raises an error in 2.2.3
  end
end

xml.test { xml.some }

### main script ###
require 'rubygems'
require 'builder'
require 'bigdecimal'

def eval_script(file)
  xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
  binding.eval(File.read(file), file)
  xml.target!
end

template = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'example.xml.builder')
puts eval_script(template)
# Ruby 1.8.7 / builder 3.2.0 => <test><data>0.23E2</data></test>
# Ruby 2.2.3 / builder 3.2.2 => ./eval_script.rb:5:in `some': uninitialized constant Builder::XmlMarkup::BigDecimal (NameError)
```

I found no reason for the behavior. How can I fix the problem?

BTW: I have the same problem with the method lookup, e.g `format('%d', 42)` which returns the full XML document but doesn't call `Kernel.format` in Ruby 2.2.3.

Comment: Try `::BigDecimal`

Comment: @MladenJablanović double colon prefix works. But then I have to change a huge amount of code in the legacy project. Is there another solution to enforce the constant lookup of Ruby 1.8.7?

Comment: not that I know of. btw you know about mass search&replace, right? :) also you have a typo up there: `imdent => 2`.

Comment: @MladenJablanović I removed the ´:indent´ configuration since it doesn't add any useful information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround overriding `const_missing` which has to be applied to every template file. It works so far for the legacy application.

```
### example.xml.builder (template) ###
class << xml
  def self.const_missing(name)
    super rescue ::Object.const_get(name)
  end

  def some
    data(BigDecimal.new('23'))
  end
end

xml.test { xml.some }
```

But every time the constant `BigDecimal` is used, it triggers `const_missing` and then raises a `NameError` and calls the `Object` method.